# Why would I get a non-zero value for mutual information for one variable, say x_m (belonging to (x_1, ..., x_n)), to target y, if x_m is a constant?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, mutual-information

I have n 'features', (x_1, ..., x_n) and a target variable y. I use sklearn's mutual information score for feature selection to determine which features are the most important for the target y. I get a non-negative value for one feature/input to this y, although this is actually just a constant, and it has one of the larger mutual information scores.

When using sklearn's mutual information for other features/targets I seem to get intuitive/sensible results, so believe I'm using it correctly. Is there any reason why someone would get a non-negative mutual information score for a variable/target y, and a constant value?